# What's it means "yes validate just the what"

Tags: american-english, slang, north-american-english

I asked my mentor

"Do I need to validate the filed if it's type is required？”

And he answered

"Yes validate just the what"

What's that means？ It it means yes I should validate it？ Or there's other meaning? And what is the actual meaning of "just the what"?

English is my second language and I'm not vary good at it, could anyone help me out？ I appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know what your question meant.

Comment: As a native speaker, I think you may have misheard your mentor because “that what” is unclear. However, they still want you to validate the field since they said “yes.”

Comment: I'll take a wild guess at an unclear answer to an unclear question. You asked if you should validate a file or a field, and you wanted to know if that is correct even if its type needs to be supplied. Your mentor said yes to the first part, *your concern is just that first part* (the what) and no more (the how).